# Global holomorphic vector field on a two-sphere

Tags: general-topology, geometry, vector-bundles

I'm sure this question has been asked before...

Till today, I thought that one cannot define a global holomorphic vector field on a two-sphere due to the hairy ball theorem. However, here's an exercise which I found on page 8 of the ["Mirror symmetry"](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=DC805EAC0D01EB861B82DB39B8B08550) book (see pic attached):[image]

Could anyone comment on this please? Doesn't defining a global holomorphic vector field on a sphere imply defining a global section on the tangent vector bundle? I am confused.

Thanks.

Comment: What you cannot do is to define a *nowhere zero* field on the sphere. You can always define a vector field, on any manifold: the zero vector field, for example.

Comment: Thanks for response! So, this field has two zeros...

But what is the value of the field at the point which corresponds to $z\to\infty$ on the first patch?

Comment: @mariano-suárez-Álvarez, why $v = a$, a constant vector field, would not be a nowhere zero vector field?

Comment: There is no such thing as a constant vector field on a manifold. The tangent spaces at different points are disjoint, so no vector field can even take the same value twice, let alone be constant.

Comment: But aren't authors talking about $v = v^z \partial_z = (a+bz+cz^2) \partial_z$? Why isn't $v = (a) \partial_z$ called a constant field?

Comment: That is the coordinate expression of the vector field in a specific coordinate chart. There are other charts with respect to which the coordinates of the vector field are not constant.